# Applying Left Join in Pentaho

Tags: kettle, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I'm try to create Transformation and need to merge two Database based on query like that by using `Merge Join` and I little bit confuse what should i filled in `First Step`, `Second Step` to Lookup for that each query format.

Query Format :

```
SELECT * FROM A a LEFT JOIN B b on a.value=b.value

SELECT * FROM A a LEFT JOIN B b on b.value=a.value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various way to do it.

- Write the sql with the join in the `Table input step`. Quick an dirty solution if your table are in the same database, but do not tell a PDI expert you did it that way.
- If you know there is only one B record for each A record, use a `Lookup Stream Step`. Very, very, very efficient. The Main flow is the A and the lookup step is B.
- If you have many B records for each A records, use a `Join Rows`. Don't be afraid, you do not really make a Cartesian product, as you can put your condition a.value=b.value.
- In the same situation, you can also make a `Merge join`. The first step is the step you write fist in the sql select statement.

Comment: Thanks @AlainD, very helpful with that various way to solve it.

Comment: At second point in your answer, it's okay applying LEFT JOIN using Stream Lookup? What about the result? It's will like LEFT JOIN in query?

Well, new case if I want merge two data from different kind of source like Between CSV and DB also applying those LEFT JOIN, is it possible? And

Comment: Yes, that the point of the Steam technology, you do not care from where the data comes in. And the difference between a LEFT JOIN (or the `join rows` step) and the `Stream Lookup` is that the former always join one record, which by experience is more than 80% of the case.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways to do this.
you can use TableInput Step and just simply write your query. No need to do anything else for implementing above query.